# Правильный счетчик вопросов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется несколько input'ов с одинаковым классом
Как узнать какой инпут по счету сейчас активен?

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <p class="maincontent__text">Вопрос <span class="maincontent__number">1</span> из 4</p>


    <div class="interview__input-wrapper">
      <div class="interview__item">
        <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Ваше имя?</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="interview__input change__input"
          placeholder="Моё имя.."
          autofocus
        />
      </div>
      <div class="interview__item">
        <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сколько Вам?</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="interview__input change__input"
          placeholder="Мой возраст.."
        />
      </div>
      <div class="interview__item">
        <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Какой стаж?</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="interview__input change__input"
          placeholder="Мой стаж.."
        />
      </div>
      <div class="interview__item">
        <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">
          Сильные стороны?
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="interview__input change__input"
          placeholder="Мои сильные стороны.."
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

я хочу сделать так чтобы счетчик считал правильно начиная с числа 1 и заканчивая последним input'ом с учетом того что их может быть больше или меньше чем в примере.

```html
maincontent__number
```

Именно в этот спан я и хочу вставлять корректный номер.

Comment: "счетчик считал правильно начиная с числа 1" - что считал?

Comment: Нужно посчитать количество инпутов? Число «1» что это?

Comment: Я пробовал реализовать просто посредством прибавления к элементу по одному после нажатия на каждый, но у меня получилось лишь сделать чтобы в конце счетчик показывал 5, если вопросов 4... То есть на один больше

Comment: Считать нужно какой инпут по счету сейчас активен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".interview__input-wrapper input").focus(function(){
  var num = $(".interview__input-wrapper input").index(this) + 1;
  $(".maincontent__number").text(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="maincontent__text">Вопрос <span class="maincontent__number"></span> из 4</p>


<div class="interview__input-wrapper">
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Ваше имя?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Моё имя.." autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сколько Вам?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой возраст.." />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Какой стаж?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой стаж.." />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">
      Сильные стороны?
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мои сильные стороны.." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @Dan Пожалуйста. Успехов!